# How to initialize a model with multidimensional arrays in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multidimensional-array

Initializing the model with multiple arrays.

I have already tried to initialize but its not working.

```
namespace ArrayTest.Models
{
    public class Question
    {
        public string question { get; set; }
        public string[] option { get; set; }
        public string[] score { get; set; }
    }
}

public class DefaultController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Question> x = new List<Question>
        {
            new Question(){ question = "Question1", option = { "abc","cde","efg"}, score = { "abc", "cde", "efg" } },
            new Question(){},
            new Question(){},
            new Question(){}
        };
        return View(x);
    }
}
```

I expect this model to be initialized and sent to the view.

Comment: you can change your code to be something like `new Question(){question="Question1", option= new string[3]
                { "abc","cde","efg"},score=new string[3]{ "abc", "cde", "efg" } ` as you are trying to initialize an `array`. So, in `C#` your have to define the type along with the size.

Comment: Please try like this option will be better rather then your code

public List<Options> options { get;set;}

Comment: @GurdeepSingh Why? and how come `List<T>` would be better? You are tight coupling then rather `IEnumerable<T>` would be better suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string[]` doesn't have an `.Add()` method, so `option = { "abc", "cde", "efg"}` won't work. You need to create the array and initialize the array:

```
var list = new List<Question>
{
    new Question()
    {
        question = "Question1",
        option = new string[] { "abc", "cde", "efg"},
        score = new string[] { "abc", "cde", "efg" }
    },

    new Question(){},
    new Question(){},
    new Question(){}
};
```

Comment: Or just `option = new [] { "abc", "cde", "efg"},`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :
Add a constructor in your modal like following,

```
 public class Question
    {
        public string question { get; set; }
        public string[] option { get; set; }
        public string[] score { get; set; }

        public Question(string question, List<string> option, List<string> score)
        {
            this.question = question;
            this.option = option.ToArray();
            this.score = score.ToArray();

        }
    }
```

Step 2:
Modify your controller method like following,

```
 IEnumerable<Question> x = new List<Question> {
                new Question("Question1", new List<string>{"cde","efg"}, new List<string> { "abc", "cde", "efg" }),
                new Question("Question2", new List<string>{"cde","efg"}, new List<string> { "abc", "cde", "efg" }) } ;
```

If you use this List, You can use .Add() method as well.